# Do teddy bears help people go to sleep better?

Tags: psychology, sleep, parenting

There are so many kids in this world who go to sleep with teddy bears and dolls.  It seems like they *need* these toys to go off to Dreamland.

I just recently realised this because my own child, about 5 yrs. old, told me he couldn't go to sleep without it. Does a teddy bear really help a person sleep better?

Are there any studies on this showing that a child actually sleeps better with a teddy bear?

What about adults? Does this affect them?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable and interesting question which I expect to yield some answers that at least touch on child psychology; I suggest adding "psychology" and "sleep" tags to this question.  I'm _voting up_ for this question despite the big -4 that I see on it now.

Comment: I also think this also worth looking at. Do children really get comfort from stuffed toys? I vote to reopen. This is _a lot_ better than some of the other questions I've seen in the past week.

Comment: I think we really ought to reopen this..

Comment: Is this question about teddy bears? Plush toys? Dolls? Favourite blankets, too? How about familiar surroundings in general, and/or routine bed-time rituals? Sleeping companions? Toys as companion substitutes?

Comment: FWIW I voted to close it as of-topic because it's not (and here I'm quoting words from the FAQ) a public, pseudo-scientific claim made in the media.

Comment: @ChrisW-- all of those objects fall under the category of 'transference object' in psychiatry and psychoanalysis.  This magazine from 20+ years ago covers some theories about it: http://www.pep-web.org/toc.php?journal=mpsa&volume=13&PHPSESSID=engaq09vptifd8dljd5d7n4dv0#66 But essentially, these objects are thought to be parental standins when parents aren't present.  I don't have the expertise to really delve into it, but it's a subject of real study.

Comment: Mr Bean needs his teddy bear to sleep, the television series shows that quite clearly :)

Comment: Mine sure works for me. I have a regular teddy and a backup teddy.  ;->

Answer (score 8):

This phenomenon is described under [co-sleeping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-sleeping) in psychology. Its based on childs being used to lying beside mother/father. In the transition phase to sleeping alone the teddy is compensation.

If a adult is affected by not having a teddy, should look for a good therapist ;)

[source](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=NGtd6HRRpMMC&oi=fnd&pg=PT8&dq=baby%20sleep%20%22own%20bed%22%20relationship%20%7C%20binding%20cry%2a%20mother%20psychology%20stuffed%20toy&ots=EWX8JHBZx2&sig=oDjWLzTp1e6QiyJUggzt2pMz7F4#v=onepage&q=stuffed%20animal&f=false)

[source](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/icd.524/abstract)

Comment: I need my bear to go to sleep, so do I need a good therapist?

Comment: `If a adult is affected by not having a teddy, should look for a good therapist` Or a loving life partner?

Comment: What if the "loving life partner" is a "bear" named Teddy?